# php modules doesn't work in wampserver configuring symfony

Tags: php, symfony, module, wampserver

I unzipped symfony in the www folder of wampserser and it's gaving me three recommendations witch are:

1. Install PHP 5.4.11 or newer if your project uses the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component.
2. Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).
3. Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).

Concerning to the second one i tried to enabled the module php_intl but as sun as i do it a warning message shows up saying "PHP Startup" two times one after the other, after all of this on loading `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php` it keeps giving me this recommendation.

In the third recommentation i downloaded the php_apc.dll don`t remember from where but on enabling it happen the same thing as the intl extension but the warning message that shows up says:

```
PHP Startup:apc: Unable to initialize module 
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

I'm using wampserver 2.3, Apache Version : 2.2.23, PHP Version : 5.4.9 
What do i have to upgrade? wampserver, PHP to 5.4.11?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What this says is basically "you are using the wrong version of this module."

In PHP the module has to be compiled for the correct PHP Version. So if you use PHP 5.4 you have to use the module compiled for PHP 5.4, not 5.3. Minor versions between for example 5.4.11 und 5.4.12 make (usually) no difference to the module.

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/3.1.13/
There you get the latest version of for your PHP Version. Check the name of the file. There is also a difference between "Thread Safe" (ts) and "Not Thread Safe" (nts). I don't know which one you have, but just try both, it'll work with your version.

Also note that since PHP 5.5 Zend OPCache is included inside PHP directly. It does basically the same but you don't have to maintain a dependency.